# Is the region of all reals an open or closed region?

Tags: calculus

Say you have some function like f(x,y) = y - x.

The domain of this function would be all reals in the xy-plane, and my textbook says that this domain is both an open region and closed region.

I'm having trouble understanding this. Since there is no boundary on the domain, how can it be a closed region?

Comment: What is your definition for *closed region*?

Comment: A region which contains its entire boundary.

Comment: And because the boundary is $\varnothing$, the region does indeed contain its entire boundary

Comment: OK, then in particular, a region without boundary is automatically closed.

Comment: Note that you do need to be a little careful when you say "closed". You should probably say "closed in $X$", where $X$ is some particular topological space (say, the entire plane). Every set is closed in itself, but that doesn't mean that it is closed in a larger space.

Comment: You can also see that the original "region" is closed because its complement in the plane (namely, $\varnothing$) is open.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ has no boundary, as you seem to notice. It then *trivially* contains its boundary since its boundary is the empty set. Every element of the empty set is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (since it has no elements!) so $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains its boundary. Thought of in a better way: is there any element in the boundary (in the empty set) that is *not* in $\mathbb{R}^2$? This is another case of the idiosyncrasies of the empty set and statements about the empty set.

Comment: Ah okay, this makes sense. I did not consider the boundary to be the empty set contained.

Comment: The empty set is a bit weird and can mess with your intuition about how things are. It takes a little while to train yourself the right way.

Comment: I truely understood the empty set when someone told me : 
"$x \in \emptyset \iff x$ verifies all properties you can imagine. In particular elements of the empty set are in $\mathbb R ^{2} $

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this wonderful answer,